# Como nomear a versão do aplicativo no Google Play Developer Console para colocar em produção?

Tags: android

Fiz upload do meu primeiro aplicativo 1.0 na área de teste alfa e depois fiz uma atualização e upload para o teste alfa com o version code 2.0 está certo usar o 2.0 ou seria melhor usar o 1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá @Thiago Philipp

Note que voce tem dois codes para versão de um app, o "VersionCode" e o "VersionName", versioncode é um numero de controle para a loja, somente voce vai ver esse numero e versãoname é o que vai aparecer para o usuario, assim o melhor seria voce usar um numero inteiro para versioncode e o que voce quiser para versionname.

eu costumo usar assim ó:

VersionCode 1
VersionName 1.0

Proxima atualização

VersionCode 2
VersionName 1.1

Proxima atualização

VersionCode 3
VersionName 1.2

e por ai vai